# Вызов метода без объекта (экземпляра класса)

Tags: java

Не очень понимаю, как мы записали getSum() в переменную. Обычно я делал так:
public int a = test.getSum(); где test это объект класса Test к примеру. Как без экземпляра вызывается? Никак не пойму.

```
public class Test {
        public int a = getSum();
        public int b = getSum() - a;
        public int c = getSum() - a - b;
    
        public int getSum() {
            return a + b + c;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как поле не статическое, и метод `getSum()` не статический, то существование объекта подразумевается. В этом случае объектом будет `this`.

Comment: То есть по факту, под капотом написано, this.getSum() поэтому он и не ругается?

Comment: Да. Если Вы обращаетесь к полю либо методу класса из самого класса, Вам не обязательно указывать `this`. Но можете и указать. Это не запрещено.